# How to implement https://schema.org/GenderType in Json

Tags: schema, json-ld

What the correct way to implement https://schema.org/GenderType for https://schema.org/Person in JSON-LD.

I Attempted bellow:

```
{ 
"@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "givenName": "First Name",
    "familyName": "Last name",
    "gender": {
        "@type": "GenderType",
        "gender" "Male"
    } 
  }
```

The following works:

```
{ 
"@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "givenName": "First Name",
    "familyName": "Last name",
    "gender": "Male" 
}
```

Though that would use https://schema.org/Text

An other solution:

```
{ 
"@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "givenName": "First Name",
    "familyName": "Last name",
    "gender": "https://schema.org/Male" 
}
```

Seems to be valid at https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
Though not sure if that how it mean to be implemented.

Comment: I went with the last version. It doesn't show any error and seems to look fine.

Comment: The second one should also be fine. You don't need to do the full URL if you have already defined it as the @context.